# reading a split in a for loop

Tags: java, calculator, equation

Recently I created a method to read an equation by splitting it and then goes into a loop that reads the part it is on to find symbols and gives the number after and before the symbol. The issue is that I do get an error but it disappears before I can see it and if I'm correct java cannot read the + sign after it is split. I'm not sure how I would be able to catch the exception without knowing what type it is so any help would be good. Thanks.

```
private void sortEquasion(){
    String[] t = Equasion.split("\\+"); // this line added on
    for(int counter = 0; counter<t.length; counter++){ // this part added
        if(t[counter].contains("+")){
            String i = t[counter -1];
            String i2 = t[counter + 1];
            System.out.println(i + i2);
        }
    }
    //if(Equasion.contains("(")){ //untage this if code above does not work

    //}
}
```

Comment: What programming environment are you using?

Comment: I am using eclipse.

Comment: You are probably getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ?. Use the "debug" option and add a breakpoint before the print statement. Also, `t[counter]` probably won't contain a `+` (since you are splitting based on `+`)

Comment: `int counter = 0;` ...  `t[counter - 1];` You are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -1`

Comment: Ok thank you guys for letting me know about that :), last thing is is that reading a split line could cause trouble because if I'm trying to separate each equation into + * / ect, then I think reading it after splitting will not detect equasion signs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which error you are seeing. But if you split on a character, that character will not show up in any string in the resulting array. For example the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String equation = "1 + 2 = 3";
    for (String s : equation.split("\\+")) {
        System.out.println( s );
    }
}
```

will result in the output:

```
1 
 2 = 3
```

Also note, as someone said, having a for loop with an index:

```
for (counter i = 0; i < counter.length; counter++) {
    // bad: index out of bounds exception on last iteration
    String s = t[counter + 1];
}
```

But that shouldn't be the exception you are seeing as that code shouldn't ever be executed as the split removes all `+`. If your code is throwing an exception (or error) but you don't what know it is (and it is getting swallowed for some reason), you can use a try catch construct:

```
try {
    ... // do stuff
} catch ( Throwable thrown ) {
    thrown.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please note, though, that catching `Throwable` is bad practice in general and blanket catching of *all* exceptions is also usually a bad idea. For actual code try to catch specific exception types.

The easiest/best way to debug it should be to set a breakpoint in your IDE and step through the code. My guess (without seeing the rest of the code) is that your error/exception is coming from some other piece of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to still try to find away to still use this method but either way in the end I'm going to switch to the Shunting-Yard algorithm.